# When can we say a design is completely RESTful?

Tags: rest, definition

I am currently studying about REST interfaces for directory services and I'm confused about RESTful interfaces. When can we say that the design is completely RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

### The REST architectural style

**REST** stands for **Re**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer. This architecture is *protocol independent* but it is *frequently* implemented over the HTTP protocol.

The REST architectural style was defined in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy Thomas Fielding's PhD dissertation. And the following set of constraints was added to this architectural style:

- [Client-server](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_2)
- [Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
- [Cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4)
- [Uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)
- [Layered system](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_6)
- [Code-on-demand](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7)

Through the application of the constraints defined above, certain architectural properties are induced, such as visibility, portability, reliability, scalability and network efficiency.

### What does RESTful mean?

The term *RESTful* could be compared to the term *object-oriented*. Programming languages could be considered object-oriented when they follow a set of concepts. An application can be considered *RESTful* when such application does not break the constraints defined above.

REST is a [resource-oriented](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) architecture. When implementing REST applications over the HTTP protocol, for example, the resource is identified by the URI and the operation over the resource is expressed by the [HTTP method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4).