# How to pass filter arguments to GET requests in REST APIs?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I'm building a RESTful webservice:

- Under `GET /clients`, I'm getting the list of all known clients.
- Under `GET /clients/1`, I'm getting the client object for the `clientId` 1.

Everything as it should be.

Those clients have a property called `authorized`. On my web UI to manage those, I have separated tables for authorized and unauthorized clients. Of course, I do not want to load all the clients from the server just to display the unauthorized ones.

The question is, how could I filter the client over a RESTful URL? As I want to do a proper RESTful API, query parameters are not an option.

I already thought about additionally doing `GET /unauthorizedClients` and `GET /authorizedClients` but this seems not right, as I still would use `DELETE`/clients/%clientId%` to remove one client.

I couldn't think of a pleasing approach for this problem. Any tips on how this could be solved are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with `/clients/unauthorized` and `/clients/authorized`. You need to taylor resource URIs like *directories*.

This way, there's nothing wrong with deleting clients against the `/client/[id]` resource.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what if been looking for.
Thanks!

Comment: @HerrDerb if `clients` both `authorized` and `unauthorized` are considered to be single resource with different state this answer doesn't make sense. Much better is to use query parameters.

Comment: @HerrDerb Actually, this is absolutely subjective. Both your point and mine... and you know it

Answer (score 2):

I'm just wondering what prevents you from using query parameters. They are the most appropriate way to filter a collection of resources in REST APIs. Using query parameters won't make your API *less* [RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593834/1426227).

You could have the following:

- Authorized: `GET /clients?status=authorized`
- Unauthorized: `GET /clients?status=unauthorized`

Another option is:

- Authorized: `GET /clients/authorized`
- Unauthorized: `GET /clients/unauthorized`

You really should consider query parameters though.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for query parameters!